# Passing XSL arguments to JS

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I try to pass a parameter to javascript in an XSL file... how do i Do that?

```
    <xsl:variable name="currentPath">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($path, ./name)"/>/
    </xsl:variable>

<script>
 someFunction(someParameter);
</script>
```

I will try that here again because of the layout:

```
<script>  document.getElementById('<xsl:value-of select="$currentPath"></xsl:value-of>').style.display = 'none'; 
</script>
```

and I am using a variable which is a parameter in a template

```
<xsl:template match="dir">  
<xsl:param name="path"/>
```

The variable is used as the id of a table:

```
<table border="0" id="$currentPath">
```

This variable is in use somewhere else, and it is working there... by the way I am on Firefox 3.5.xx

Another EDIT:
I put

```
<xsl:value-of select="$currentPath"/>
```

right before the script tag and the result was expected... the variable is not the problem...

Comment: From where do you pass? You first need the `<xsl:param name="paramname" />` then `someFunction('<xsl:value-of select="$paramname"></xsl:value-of>')`

Comment: Did you wrap the javascript in <!-- --> (you should not)

Comment: no of course not... thx for your effort btw!

Answer (score 0):

Use curly braces around the reference in the table element:

```
<table border="0" id="{$currentPath}">
```